# How to upgrade python version from python2 to python3 in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

I have both the version of python.I have also installed jupyter notebook individually and when i open the jupyter notebook and go to new section it is showing python 2

I want to use python3 for newer packages.So how can we upgrade the python version.

Comment: you can use the kernel option in the notebook to change the kernel to a different environment

Comment: @Akshay not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More systematic approach would be

1 Install [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
$ export WORKON_HOME=~/Envs
$ mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
$ mkvirtualenv -p $(which python3) jupyter_notebook
```

2 Install jupyter in this environment

```
(jupyter_notebook)$ pip install jupyter
```

3 Run notebook

```
(jupyter_notebook)$ jupyter notebook
```

4 To install new packages don't forget to activate newly created virtual environment

```
$ workon jupyter_notebook
(jupyter_notebook)$ pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

If the kernel was not visible in the kernel options you will have to configure it manually. This is how I did it on my macos.

```
python3 -m pip install ipykernel
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

After running these commands you should be able to see the kernel in the change kernel option.

[image]